# find (i,j) location of closest (long,lat) values in a 2D array

Tags: python

I have multiple 2D arrays, three of which are LONG, LAT and HEIGHT. I would like to determine the closest index in these 2D arrays for a given (long,lat).

So, within my 2D HEIGHT array, what is the index of (-43.5,45)?

Comment: you need to post ur code, error, expected input and expected output

Comment: Do the 2d arrays have any specific structure? Sorted somehow, or do they have any relation?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Closest point to a given point](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901139/closest-point-to-a-given-point)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few foolish minutes later; I have worked out an answer I believe sufficient:

```
a = abs( LAT-chosen_lat ) + abs( LONG-chosen_lon )

i,j = np_unravel_index(a.argmin(), a.shape)
```