# Computing the least distance between coordinate pairs

Tags: python, dataframe

First dataframe df1 contains id and their corresponding two coordinates. For each coordinate pair in the first dataframe, i have to loop through the second dataframe to find the one with the least distance. I tried taking the individual coordinates and finding the distance between them but it does not work as expected. I believe it has to be taken as a pair when finding the distance between them. Not sure whether Python offers some methods to achieve this.

For eg: df1

```
Id        Co1            Co2
334    30.371353      -95.384010
337    39.497448      -119.789623
```

df2

```
Id       Co1             Co2
339    40.914585      -73.892456
441    34.760395      -77.999260

dfloc3 =[[38.991512-77.441536],
         [40.89869-72.37637],
         [40.936115-72.31452],
         [30.371353-95.38401],
         [39.84819-75.37162],
         [36.929306-76.20035],
         [40.682342-73.979645]]


dfloc4 = [[40.914585,-73.892456],
          [41.741543,-71.406334],
          [50.154522,-96.88806],
          [39.743565,-121.795761],
          [30.027597,-89.91014],
          [36.51881,-82.560844],
          [30.449587,-84.23629],
          [42.920475,-85.8208]]
```

Comment: What output do you expect? How are you calculating the distance between coordinates. Are you using pythagoras? Please show us your code.

Comment: This might help: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/28207/110101 or this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1901139/4996248

Comment: dfloc3 = [[38.991512-77.441536],
[40.89869-72.37637],
[40.936115-72.31452],
[30.371353-95.38401],
[39.84819-75.37162],
[36.929306-76.20035],
[40.682342-73.979645]]


dfloc4 = [[40.914585,-73.892456],
[41.741543,-71.406334],
[50.154522,-96.88806],
[39.743565,-121.795761],
[30.027597,-89.91014],
[36.51881,-82.560844],
[30.449587,-84.23629],
[42.920475,-85.8208]]

Comment: Are `dfloc3` and `dfloc4` your expected output? If so, how did you calculate them? Or are you trying to find the nearest point in `df2` for each point in `df1`? Or the nearest point in `dfloc3` for each point in `df1`?

Answer (score 1):

The code below creates a new column in `df1` showing the Id of the nearest point in `df2`. (I can't tell from the question if this is what you want.) I'm assuming the coordinates are in a Euclidean space, i.e., that the distance between points is given by the Pythagorean Theorem. If not, you could easily use some other calculation instead of `dist_squared`.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict(Id=[334, 337], Co1=[30.371353, 39.497448], Co2=[-95.384010, -119.789623]))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict(Id=[339, 441], Co1=[40.914585, 34.760395], Co2=[-73.892456, -77.999260]))

def nearest(row, df):
    # calculate euclidian distance from given row to all rows of df
    dist_squared = (row.Co1 - df.Co1) ** 2 + (row.Co2 - df.Co2) ** 2
    # find the closest row of df
    smallest_idx = dist_squared.argmin()
    # return the Id for the closest row of df
    return df.loc[smallest_idx, 'Id']

near = df1.apply(nearest, args=(df2,), axis=1)

df1['nearest'] = near
```

Answer (score 1):

Given you can get your points into a list like so...

```
df1 = [[30.371353, -95.384010], [39.497448, -119.789623]]
df2 = [[40.914585, -73.892456], [34.760395, -77.999260]]
```

Import math then create a function to make finding the distance easier:

```
import math    

def distance(pt1, pt2):
    return math.sqrt((pt1[0] - pt2[0])**2 + (pt1[1] - pt2[1])**2)
```

Then simply transverse your your list saving the closest points:

```
for pt1 in df1:
    closestPoints = [pt1, df2[0]]
    for pt2 in df2:
        if distance(pt1, pt2) < distance(closestPoints[0], closestPoints[1]):
            closestPoints = [pt1, pt2]
    print ("Point: " + str(closestPoints[0]) + " is closest to " + str(closestPoints[1]))
```

Outputs:

```
Point: [30.371353, -95.38401] is closest to [34.760395, -77.99926]
Point: [39.497448, -119.789623] is closest to [34.760395, -77.99926]
```

Comment: @Nick.M: I am getting the error 'list index out of range'. Not sure why I am getting this. I have added the list in the question.

Comment: Your first list needs to separate the x and y with a , like you did in the second one